# Async iterators and generators: Streaming GeoJSONL

Tags: javascript, async-await, async-iterator

I'm trying to replicate [Brett Camper's code](https://observablehq.com/@bcamper/streaming-geojsonl) about streaming GeoJSONL files, and it is quite complex.

I'm trying to understand what it does step by step, but I really can't figure out what this syntax does:

```
streamGeoJSONL = async ƒ*(url)
```

Anyone can please explain it to me? If possible I would like to find something about it on [Mozilla web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).

Also, if someone could explain to me the flow of the code in the given example I would REALLY appreciate that!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you see the syntax `async function*`, it means the function is an **AsyncGenerator**. You can consume an `AsyncGenerator` by using [for await...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of) on its generated `AsyncIterator`

```js
async function* streamGeoJSONL(url) {...} // AsyncGenerator

const url = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/vtiles/honolulu_hawaii.geojsonl"

streamGeoJSONL(url) // => AsyncIterator
```

You get an `AsyncIterator` when you call an `AsyncGenerator`. That's what `AsyncGenerator` generates: an `AsyncIterator`

You can consume an `AsyncIterator` with `for await...of`

```js
for await (const newFeatures of streamGeoJSONL(url)) {/* do stuff with newFeatures */}
```

In the case of your example, `newFeatures` takes on the value that sent back by the keyword `yield` in `streamGeoJSONL`

```js
async function* streamGeoJSONL(url) {
  // ...
  yield lines.map(JSON.parse) // this is newFeatures
} // AsyncGenerator
```